# InventorySum (Running value) in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using ADF to make a table with the running value of an Inventory. But I can't seem to get it to work the way I want to.
My dataset looks like bit this (Not the real dataset)

```
I know I might not need the PrevSum Column, but it here to make it more transparant;

CurrSum = PrevSum + SalesQty + PurchQty  

- or more correct would be saying ->

CurrSum = (CurrSum from Previous record) + SalesQty + PurchQty

ItemNo CurrSum PrevSum SalesQty PurchQty FromDate EndDate
A          0.0     0.0     -1.0      1.0   01.jan  31.jan
A          0.0     0.0     -5.0     50.0   01.feb  28.feb
A          0.0     0.0    -10.0      0.0   01.mar  31.mar
A          0.0     0.0      0.0     10.0   01.apr  30.apr
A          0.0     0.0     -6.0      0.0   01.may  31.may
A          0.0     0.0     -1.0      0.0   01.jun  30.jun
```

In ADF, I have used the "Window Transformation", to solve this, where.;

```
1."Over" is set to the 'ItemNo' (Partition)
2."Sort" is set to be  'EndDate'
3."Range by" is set to 'Unbound'. 
4."Wíndow columns" looks like this;

Cloumn    Expression
CurrSum   iifNull(lag(CurrSum,1),0, lag(CurrSum,1) + PurchQty + SalesQty)
```

I would expect the lag(CurrSum,1) to take the previous record vaule but it does not work. What I'm I doing wrong ?

I have tried to set "Range by" like this ;
[Range by offset by 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIK9q.png)

But gets this error; "Cannot specify window frame for lag function"

The expected outcome is;

```
ItemNo CurrSum PrevSum SalesQty PurchQty FromDate EndDate
A          0.0     0.0     -1.0      1.0   01.jan  31.jan
A         45.0     0.0     -5.0     50.0   01.feb  28.feb
A         35.0    45.0    -10.0      0.0   01.mar  31.mar
A         45.0    35.0      0.0     10.0   01.apr  30.apr
A         39.0    45.0     -6.0      0.0   01.may  31.may
A         38.0    39.0     -1.0      0.0   01.jun  30.jun
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the required output, you can follow the procedure below:

Create the required data as a dataset and select it as the source. Project it according to the requirement. Add an aggregate transformation to the source group by all columns except the `CurrSum` column, and aggregate the `CurrSum` column using the expression below:

```
sum(PrevSum + SalesQty + PurchQty)
```

Add a window transformation to the aggregate transformation as follows:

```
1. "Over" is set to the 'ItemNo' (Partition)
2. "Sort" is set to be 'EndDate'
3. "Range by" is set to 'Unbound'
4. "Window columns" looks like this:

Column    Expression
PrevSum   lag(CurrSum, 1)
```

Add a second window transformation to the window transformation as follows:

```
1. "Over" is set to the 'ItemNo' (Partition)
2. "Sort" is set to be 'EndDate'
3. "Range by" is set to 'Unbound'
4. "Window columns" looks like this:

Column    Expression
CurrSum   sum(SalesQty+PurchQty)
```

Add a third window transformation to the second window transformation as follows:

```
1. "Over" is set to the 'ItemNo' (Partition)
2. "Sort" is set to be 'EndDate'
3. "Range by" is set to 'Unbound'
4. "Window columns" looks like this:

Column    Expression
PrevSum   lag(CurrSum, 1)
```

Add a select transformation to get columns in the required format. You will get the output as shown below:

[image]

Add it to the sink with the required dataset. For more information, you can check the dataflow script representation below:

```
source(output(
        ItemNo as string,
        CurrSum as float,
        PrevSum as float,
        SalesQty as float,
        PurchQty as float,
        FromDate as date 'dd/MM/yyyy',
        EndDate as date 'dd/MM/yyyy'
    ),
    allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source1
source1 aggregate(groupBy(ItemNo,
        PrevSum,
        SalesQty,
        PurchQty,
        FromDate,
        EndDate),
    CurrSum = sum(PrevSum + SalesQty + PurchQty )) ~> aggregate1
aggregate1 window(over(ItemNo),
    asc(FromDate, true),
    PrevSum = lag(CurrSum, 1)) ~> window1
window1 window(over(ItemNo),
    asc(EndDate, true),
    CurrSum =  sum(SalesQty+PurchQty)) ~> window2
window2 window(over(ItemNo),
    asc(EndDate, true),
    PrevSum = lag(CurrSum, 1)) ~> window3
window3 select(mapColumn(
        ItemNo,
        CurrSum,
        PrevSum,
        SalesQty,
        PurchQty,
        FromDate,
        EndDate
    ),
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1
select1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> sink1
```